# Tradeoffs "upgrading" from a 60/900 refractor to a 150/1200 Dobsonian?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing

My current/previous telescope is a [Skywatcher 60/900](https://teleskop-austria.com/SWR609eq1_SkyWatcher-Luna-60-60-900-refractor-telescope-on-EQ1) refractor on an equatorial mount. I am now looking at a [SkyWatcher 150/1200](https://www.astroshop.eu/telescopes/skywatcher-dobson-telescope-n-150-1200-skyliner-classic-dob/p,15559) "Classic" [Dobsonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobsonian_telescope) reflector.

How can I compare the two in terms of ease of use? What will be easier to do, and to see with the larger Dobsonian?  What will be harder?

I want to see planets, galaxy, nebula, etc.

Comment: The Help Centre says [it's on-topic to ask](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about "What type of equipment will allow you to see a certain entity", so I recommend you [edit] your question to include where you live (city or region is sufficient), what you want to look at (eg the Moon, Jupiter, the Pinwheel Galaxy NGC 5457?) and your level of experience. You should [*avoid* asking subjective or open-ended questions](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), so you need to remove "is this good or not?" :-)

Comment: Okay,but  i really want to hear what people think.My previous telescope is skywatcher 60/900 how much is better 150/1200?I want to see planets,galaxy,nebula...

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Exchange!** I've edited your question's wording to better fit the site's style, to avoid asking for opinions or "what people think" and to avoid being a "shopping question". This will prevent your question from being closed and help it to be answered. I'm not sure about the link to your 60/900, if you can find a better one please feel free to add it, or to adjust the wording in general. *Thanks!*

Comment: The short answer is that the aperture is much bigger so at the same magnification nebulae and galaxies will look about 6 times brighter, but if you were used to using the equatorial mount to track objects as they move then the Dobsonian mount might be a little frustrating. It would be great if you could find an astronomy club somewhere and discuss or even observe with others first before investing in a very different kind of telescope. *That's where to ask what people thing!* :-)

Comment: Also your useable magnification will be better, so you will see some more details on the larger planets and the Moon on nights when the atmosphere is still and [astronomical seeing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_seeing) is good. I think you should add a little more about how you plan to observe and what kind of location(s) you'll be viewing from: city vs rural, low vs higher elevation, etc.

Comment: @uhoh  Thank you.I want to as as much as i can,Planets,nebula,galaxy...Link of my currently telescope : https://teleskop-austria.com/SWR609eq1_SkyWatcher-Luna-60-60-900-refractor-telescope-on-EQ1

Comment: Okay thanks! I've updated the link in the question. Have you used the equatorial mount much? Do you set it up with the polar axis pointing towards the North or South celestial poles so that you can easily track the movement of objects with one knob? Will you miss it if you move to a Dobsonian where you have to *guide the telescope by hand* regularly? *Please tell us more* about how you've used your previous telescope! The more you describe your observing habits, the better that people can help address your quesiton.

Comment: See the red arrow here https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NMbw.png from page 12 in https://teleskop-austria.com/information/pdf/SWR609eq1_deutsch-SW_EQ1_EQ2.pdf I think you have EQ1 based on your link, so you have fine controls for both RA (red arrow) to follow movement as the Earth turns, and DEC (other long knob). Do you use them? Do you like them? If so note that the Dobsonian requires you to push your telescope to move it. Small movements can be a real challenge.

Comment: @uhoh Yes,i use them.I know..I will use small magnification until I get used to it